# IIS Plesk - changing the FastCGI protocol for PHP from Named Pipe to TCP

Tags: php, iis, fastcgi

How can I change the FastCGI protocol for PHP from Named Pipe to TCP? All I have found in Plesk settings is to turn FastCGI on and off

I'm asking it because of this answer:

[PHP Exec (ffmpeg) fails on IIS every other request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46067127/php-exec-ffmpeg-fails-on-iis-every-other-request)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could set the TCP protocol for PHP fast CGI by following below steps:

1)Open iis manger.

2)Select the Fastcgi setting click on your PHP correct path.

[image]

3)Under the advance setting set protocol to TCP:

[image]